# SQLite CRUD via Flask Form

Tags: python, sqlite, flask

I have a very strange issue here.

I'm using `SQLite` with python and `Flask` + `Flask-Sqlalchemy`.

I'm developing a flask web application with a CRUD feature (although at the moment there's no need for the D), I have a `models.py`, `routes.py`, `form.py`, `table.py`

The `table.py` displays the data that the user intends to update (via a flask table with a link to the update page) before performing the update. This link calls a specific update route in the routes.py file.

I can add/read data to/from my SQLite table both via the terminal and via the flask form with no issues, I can also update the data via the terminal directly in the SQLite table using dB.session.commit after assigning new values to overwrite the old values. However, the update fails when attempting via the flask form using the same update route and form values used via the terminal.

**form.py**

```
class SearchResultForm(FlaskForm):
    agreement_no = StringField('Agreement No')
    product = StringField('Product')
    manufacturer = StringField('Manufacturer')
    model = StringField('Model')
    vehicle_age = StringField('Vehicle Age')
    centre = StringField('Centre')
    company = StringField('Company')
    title = StringField('Title')
    first_name = StringField('First Name')
    middle_name = StringField('Middle Name')
    last_name = StringField('Last Name')
    contact_no = StringField('Contact No')
    email = StringField('Email Address ')
    adviser = StringField('Adviser')
    complaint_no = StringField('Complaint No')
    complaint_status = SelectField('Complaint Status', validators=[DataRequired()]
                                   , choices=complaint_status_choices, default=complaint_status_choices[0])
    complaint_group = StringField('Complaint Group')
    complaint_source = StringField('Complaint Source')
    complaint_narrative = TextAreaField('Complaint Narrative')
    severity = SelectField('Severity', validators=[DataRequired()], choices=severity_choices, default=severity_choices[0])
    date_received = DateTimeField('Date Received')
    reg_due_date = DateTimeField('Reg. Due Date')
    date_modified = DateTimeField('Date Modified', validators=[DataRequired()], default=dt.utcnow)
    date_acknowledged = DateTimeField('Date Acknowledged', format='%d/%m/%Y', default=dt.utcnow)
    date_escalated = DateTimeField('Date Escalated', format='%d/%m/%Y', default=dt.utcnow)
    company_outcome = SelectField('Company Outcome', choices=company_outcome_choices, default=company_outcome_choices[0])
    regulatory_outcome = SelectField('Regulatory Outcome', choices=regulatory_outcome_choices,
                                  default=regulatory_outcome_choices[0])
    regulatory_reportable = SelectField('Regulatory Reportable'
                                        , choices=yes_no_choices, default=yes_no_choices[0])
    goodwill_offered = SelectField('Goodwill Offered', choices=yes_no_choices, default=yes_no_choices[0])
    goodwill_reason = StringField('Goodwill Reason')
    goodwill_method = StringField('Goodwill Method')
    goodwill_narrative = TextAreaField('Goodwill Narrative')
    goodwill_amount = IntegerField('Goodwill Amount', default=0.00)
    submit = SubmitField('Update')
```

**models.py**

```
class Complaint(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, default=complaint_id)
    complaint_group = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    complaint_source = db.Column(db.String(60), nullable=False)
    complaint_status = db.Column(db.String(30), nullable=False)
    severity = db.Column(db.String(30), nullable=False)
    complaint_narrative = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    agreement_no = db.Column(db.String(60), nullable=True)
    product = db.Column(db.String(60), nullable=True)
    manufacturer = db.Column(db.String(60), nullable=True)
    model = db.Column(db.String(30), nullable=True)
    vehicle_age = db.Column(db.String(30), nullable=True)
    centre = db.Column(db.String(150), nullable=True)
    company = db.Column(db.String(150), nullable=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=True)
    first_name = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=True)
    middle_name = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=True)
    last_name = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=True)
    contact_no = db.Column(db.String(60), nullable=True)
    date_received = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=dt.utcnow, nullable=True)
    reg_due_date = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=(dt.utcnow() + timedelta(days=56)), nullable=True)
    date_modified = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=dt.utcnow, nullable=True)
    date_escalated = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=dt.utcnow, nullable=True)
    date_acknowledged = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=dt.utcnow, nullable=True)
    company_outcome = db.Column(db.String(60), nullable=True)
    regulatory_outcome = db.Column(db.String(60), nullable=True)
    regulatory_reportable = db.Column(db.String(10), nullable=True)
    goodwill_offered = db.Column(db.String(10), nullable=True)
    goodwill_method = db.Column(db.String(60), nullable=True)
    goodwill_reason = db.Column(db.String(60), nullable=True)
    goodwill_narrative = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=True)
    goodwill_amount = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Complaint('{self.id}', '{self.complaint_group}', '{self.complaint_source}'," \
               f" '{self.complaint_status}', '{self.complaint_narrative}','{self.severity}' ,{self.date_received}," \
               f" {self.date_modified}, {self.date_acknowledged},{self.date_escalated}, " \
               f"{self.reg_due_date},'{self.manufacturer}', '{self.model}'," \
               f"'{self.vehicle_age}','{self.product}', '{self.agreement_no}'," \
               f"'{self.title}','{self.first_name}', '{self.middle_name}'," \
               f"'{self.last_name}','{self.email}', '{self.contact_no}'," \
               f"'{self.company}','{self.company_outcome}', '{self.regulatory_outcome}'," \
               f"'{self.regulatory_reportable}','{self.goodwill_offered}', '{self.goodwill_reason}'," \
               f"'{self.goodwill_method}','{self.goodwill_narrative}','{self.goodwill_amount}', '{self.user_id}')"
```

**routes.py**

```
def update_complaint(id):
    complaint = Complaint.query.filter_by(id=id).first_or_404()

    form = SearchResultForm()

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        complaint.agreement_no = form.agreement_no.data,
        complaint.complaint_status = form.complaint_status.data,
        complaint.severity = form.severity.data,
        # complaint.date_modified = None,
        # complaint.date_escalated = None,
        # complaint.date_acknowledged = None,
        complaint.company_outcome = form.company_outcome.data
        complaint.regulatory_outcome = form.regulatory_outcome.data,
        complaint.regulatory_reportable = form.regulatory_reportable.data
        complaint.goodwill_offered = form.goodwill_offered.data,
        complaint.goodwill_method = form.goodwill_method.data,
        complaint.goodwill_reason = form.goodwill_reason.data,
        complaint.goodwill_narrative = form.goodwill_narrative.data,
        complaint.goodwill_amount = form.goodwill_amount.data,
        complaint.adviser = current_user
        db.session.commit()
        flash(f'Complaint no {form.complaint_no.data} updated successfully!', 'success')
        return redirect(url_for('home', id=complaint.id))
```

Errors I have been getting is as follows:

1. sqlalchemy.exc.StatementError: (builtins.TypeError) SQLite DateTime type only accepts Python datetime and date objects as input. **[I have checked the type of the object and it is in fact a python datetime object, I have also tried to convert to a custom datetime object with no success]**
2. sqlalchemy.exc.InterfaceError: (sqlite3.InterfaceError) Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.**[I should point out that I have been able to successfully update the SQLite table via the terminal using the same values that the form receives]**

**What am I missing here?**

Environment: [Windows 10 Professional + Pycharm Professional 2020.1]

Comment: This question needs data that reliably reproduces the problem.